# Computer wont boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb

**This is not linked to hackintosh in any way, its to do with the computer and not the software**

For the past 3 weeks, I have been trying to boot the hackintosh installer (Yosemite zone and many others) but once I select USB from the boot selection, it just returns to the TOSHIBA logo and continues booting. This has also happened with windows 7's installer on another USB. So this doesn't affect one thing. But for some reason, the windows 7 and hackintosh installer boot perfectly and work fine on my HP Compaq CQ58.

The computer I'm trying to install it on to is a TOSHIBA satellite C50-B-14D

**EDIT: Secure boot is disabled, its on CSM and USB is set as a boot device**

Comment: Your computer probably has "secure boot" enabled so it only accepts devices with the correct boot signatures. If you can check your computer BIOS tit should tell you the boot options - including Secure Boot

Comment: I forgot to add that, but secure boot is disabled. If it was enabled, a message would appear saying `Secure boot is enabled` or something along the lines.

Comment: Also, make sure you have your boot options set to use USB as a boot device. Additionally, even through you may have "secure boot" disabled, you may have an option that allows different types of boot - often listed as "CSM/Legacy"

Comment: Its on CSM and USB is set as a boot device (The top)

Answer (score 0):

[Plop Boot Manager](http://plop.at/) will add a item to your boot menu where you can boot from a USB. This will work even if your BIOS does not support it.

1. Download and extract the zip
2. In the Windows folder of the extracted files, run InstallToBootMenu.bat
3. Reboot, and choose Plop Boot Manager